# Tensorflow CNN - Dense layer as Softmax layer input

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution, softmax

I'm trying to replicate the CNN described in
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3b57/85ca3c29c963ae396c2f94ba1a805c787cc8.pdf

and I'm stuck at the last layer. I've modeled the cnn like this

```
# Model function for CNN
def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):

  # Input Layer
  # Reshape X to 4-D tensor: [batch_size, width, height, channels]
  # Taxes images are 150x150 pixels, and have one color channel
  input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 150, 150, 1])

  # Convolutional Layer #1
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 150, 150, 1]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 144, 144, 20]
  conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=input_layer,
      filters=20,
      kernel_size=[7, 7],
      padding="valid",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Pooling Layer #1
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 144, 144, 20]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 36, 36, 20]
  pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[4, 4], strides=4)

  # Convolutional Layer #2
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 36, 36, 20]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 32, 32, 50]
  conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=pool1,
      filters=50,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="valid",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Pooling Layer #2
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 32, 32, 50]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 8, 8, 50]
  pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[4, 4], strides=4)

  # Flatten tensor into a batch of vectors
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 8, 8, 50]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 8 * 8 * 50]
  pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 8 * 8 * 50])

  # Dense Layer #1
  # Densely connected layer with 1000 neurons
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 8 * 8 * 50]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 1000]
  dense1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1000, activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Dense Layer #2
  # Densely connected layer with 1000 neurons
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 1000]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 1000]
  dense2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense1, units=1000, activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Add dropout operation; 0.5 probability that element will be kept
  dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
      inputs=dense2, rate=0.5, training=mode == learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

  # Logits layer
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 1000]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 4]
  logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=nClass)

  loss = None
  train_op = None

  # Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
  if mode != learn.ModeKeys.INFER:
    onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=nClass)
    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
        onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)

  # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
  if mode == learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
        learning_rate=0.001,
        optimizer="SGD")

  # Generate Predictions
  predictions = {
      "classes": tf.argmax(
          input=logits, axis=1)
  }

  # Return a ModelFnOps object
  return model_fn_lib.ModelFnOps(
      mode=mode, predictions=predictions, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
```

but the final accuracy is really poor (0.25). So I realized that actually the paper states that the last layer is a softmax layer. So i tried changed my logits layer to

```
logits = tf.layers.softmax(dropout)
```

but when I run it, it says

```
ValueError: Shapes (?, 1000) and (?, 4) are incompatible
```

So, what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original one was correct. The softmax activation is applied while calculating the loss with `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy`. If you want to calculate it separately you should add it after the logits calculation, but without replacing it as you did.

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=nClass)
softmax = tf.layers.softmax(logits)
```

Or you can combine both in one, but I wouldn't recommend it. It is better to calculate the softmax with the loss.

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=nClass, activation=tf.layers.softmax)
```

Your classifier is not doing better than random, so I would say that the problem lays somewhere else, maybe in the data loading and preprocessing.

Comment: you were absolutely right: after normalizing the input, I started getting the right results. Thanks a lot.